# Metodo isEmpty Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

Apenas estoy aprendiendo Spring Boot y Java y este es mi código:

```
@Service
public class CostumeService {

    @Autowired
    private CostumeRepository costumeRepository;
    
    public List<Costume> getAll() {
        return costumeRepository.getAll();
    }
    
    public Optional <Costume> getCostume(int id) {
        return costumeRepository.getCostume(id);
    }
    
    public Costume save(Costume costume) {
        if (costume.getId() == null) {
            return costumeRepository.save(costume);
        } else {
            Optional<Costume> entry = costumeRepository.getCostume(costume.getId());
            
            if (entry.isEmpty()) {
                return costumeRepository.save(costume);
            } else {
                return costume;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

el método `isEmpty()` me marca error:

```
cannot find symbol, symbol: method isEmpty(), location:variable of type Optional<Costume>---.
```

Lo que necesito es que cuando el campo `id` este vacío me coloque el id autoincremental que ya definí en la interfaz `CostumeCrudRepository`, la cual `extends` de `CrudRepository`.

¿Qué está mal en esta lógica y cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: Qué versión de Java estás usando? `isEmpty()` se añadió en Java 11, si usas java 8 deberás usar `!isPresent()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a el mensaje de error al usar `isEmpty()`:

> location:variable of type Optional

deberìas usar `.isPresent()` , por ejemplo:

```
if (entry.isPresent()) {
    return costumeRepository.save(costume);
} else {
   return costume;
}
```

Comment: Gracias , me funciona perfecto!